# Displaying Dictionary Keys in Tkinter Treeview

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, treeview

I have a list of websites, the product title, price, and stock status as key pairs in a dictionary called "masterlist".

```
masterlist = [{'store': 'examplestore1.com', 'title': 'exampletitle1', 'price': '£99', 'stock': 'Sold Out'}, {'store': 'examplestore2.com', 'title': 'exampletitle2', 'price': '£12.99', 'stock': 'Sold Out'}]
```

I'm trying to display this in a simple treeview using tkinter, I have the treeview created but cannot insert the values. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: please add a reproducible code of what you've tried

Comment: How many such dictionary do you have? If I'm not wrong, this is just supposed to be one row of the `Treeview`.

Comment: I'll try and post some code that I have tried, right now this is incorporated into a tkinter GUI that has a lot of other things going on. @CoolCloud I have about 40 lines in my dictionary ie 40 different stores, I believe from my example I should have two lines in the treeview as there are two stores but I'm having trouble inserting them using the dictionary keys. Ideally I should have a treeview with headers "store", title", "price", "stock" etc. and for each store's info to be displayed underneath the headers

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65530603/12198502

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to run a loop that adds the values for each of the dictionaries in the list.

The following code will work assuming the name of your treeview is 'treeview':

```
for index, value in enumerate(masterlist):
    treeview.insert("", 'end', values=(
       masterlist[index]['store'],            
       masterlist[index]['title'],
       masterlist[index]['price'],
       masterlist[index]['stock'])
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through the list and insert the records using `Treeview.insert()` function:

```py
# "tv" is the instance of Treeview
for row in masterlist:
    tv.insert("", "end", values=(row["store"], row["title"], row["price"], row["stock"]))
```

Comment: Thank you to both for the loop solution @ZisheSchnitzler